# Can not call "gcc" from inside a Java program

Tags: java, cygwin

I am trying to call the GNU C compiler from a Java program to compile c++ file, but I get an error:

Here is the program

```
class HelloWorld { 
public static void main(String[] args)  { 
Runtime sys = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
 try {
     String com = "g++ NB.cpp -o NNN";
     System.out.println(com);
     Process p = sys.exec(com);
 }
 catch (Exception ep) {
     System.err.println(ep);}
} 
 }
```

Here is what I get when I compiler and run the program

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
$java HelloWorld
Hello World!
gcc NB.cpp -o NB
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "g++": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Here is where the gcc is resides

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

And here if the contents of the PATH

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windo
ws/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/d/SourceForge/vectorpascalcom: D:/Cygwin/bin:/cygdrive/d/make382:/cygdrive/d/usr/bin:/cygdrive/d/Program Files/TortoiseSV
N/bin:/cygdrive/d/SourceForge/vectorpascalcom:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin
```

Can any one help?

Comment: It is most likely a permissions issue. The idea should work, but most likely your JVM doesn't have the right to invoke g++. Try running another executable and watching the output.

Comment: try to use absolute path for g++, instead of rely on PATH

Comment: I tried the absolute path, but the problem still exist!

Comment: I tried running another executable file, which already display some results, through the same program, but I did not run at all.

Comment: @You: Have a look at my deleted answer. A moderator thought it doesn't answer the question, well maybe it doesn't, but surely it does more than the other two answers. In short: this is no Java problem, make `g++` run from the command prompt and it'll run from Java too.

Comment: Both g++ and gcc run normal. I even copied the same line "g++ NB.cpp -o NNN" in the program which invokes the g++ to the command prompt, and it compiled the program NB.cpp without any problem.

Comment: @You: On my computer `g++` doesn't run from the **Windows command prompt**. It simply can't since it's a symlink as ak2 wrote.

Answer (score 4):

`g++` in Cygwin usually is a symlink to either `g++-3` or `g++-4`, but Cygwin symlinks aren't transparent to non-Cygwin programs. Therefore you need to invoke the symlink target directly.

Comment: That's it - at least on my computer. Here the target is `/etc/alternatives/g++`, without any extension, so it probably can't be executed on Windoze anyway. Making a copy called `g++.exe` brought me further (to another problem which is probably specific to XP 64).

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that; /etc/alternatives/g++ is another symlink. Making a copy does work of course, but the drawback is that things might get inconsistent when there's an update.

Comment: You're right, making a copy is wrong. The symlink leads to `/usr/bin/g++-4.exe`, but I can see no Windows directory corresponding to`/usr/bin`. Finally I've found `C:\Programs\cygwin\bin\g++-4.exe`, which complains when no input files are given, but otherwise does nothing at all. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the java application through cygwin and not just a normal windows command shell. Also, try running the command on your own to make sure it's working.

And finally, this might not be applicable to your issue, but you should read the famous article [when Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) anyway.

Comment: Well, 
I am running it through Cygwin.
The commend “gcc NP.cpp –o NN” on its own from Cygwin works fine, but not from a Java program.

Comment: Have you tried the command that your program is running? G++ not gcc.

Comment: Yes, but I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with this:

```
java.security.AccessController.doPriveleged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object Run() {
        Runtime sys = Runtime.getRuntime();
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
        try {
            String com = "g++ NB.cpp -o NNN";
            System.out.println(com);
            Process p = sys.exec(com);
        }
        catch (Exception ep) {
            System.err.println(ep);}
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't help, since the problem is running *cygwin* program from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `javac` and `java` are Cygwin executables (i.e., they don't use `cygwin1.dll`), so they're not going to recognize Cygwin-specific file paths.  You can execute them from a Cygwin shell, but you can do the same with any other non-Cygwin Windows executable.  As far as your Java process is concerned, `g++` isn't `/usr/bin/g++`, because there is no `/usr/bin` directory.  (`/usr/bin` is actually a Cygwin mount point; the corresponding Windows directory is `C:\cygwin\bin`.)

Try this:

```
 String com = "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\sh -c 'g++ NB.cpp -o NNN'";
 System.out.println(com);
 Process p = sys.exec(com);
```